# Finding a upper bound for a complex and algebraic function.

Tags: complex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, analytic-functions, entire-functions

I am stuck in understanding a proof, where I don't really understand one step, which i specify below: (suposse that $f$ is holomorphic, thus analytic)

(I have no information about the holomorphism domain of $f$).

**Result.** If $\phi(x,y)$ is an algebraic function in both variables, i.e. there are polynomials $P_k(x,y)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^{N}P_k(x,y)[\phi(x,y)]^k = 0
\end{equation*}
and also let $f$ be a holomorphic function such that
\begin{equation*}
|f(z)|^2 = \phi(x,y)
\end{equation*}
then $|f(z)|^2 \leq C|z|^m$, for some $m$.

**EDIT.** Based on @MartinR comment, $f(z)=z+1$ would be a counterexample for the inequality above, which makes it invalid. Instead, he suggested (and very well) that:
\begin{equation*}
|f(z)|^2 \leq C(1+|z|^m), \hspace{.2cm} \text{ for some $m$}
\end{equation*}
which would also verify the demonstration I am talking about in the beginning.

This is a step that appears in a proof, and I tried to write it formally as a proposition/theorem above.
I would like to know where this comes from, and even if it's valid, since it's not making much sense to me. Mainly coming here to understand the result and the proof itself, not building it by myself.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Replacing $\phi$ by $\phi f$ for some polynomial $f$ you can assume that $p$ monic in $\phi$. If $\phi(a,b)$ is too large then $p(\phi(a,b),a,b)=0$ can't hold.

Comment: By the way, holomorphic is equivalent to being analytic, but these are not equivalent to being entire. Entire functions are those which are holomorphic, or equivalently, analytic, in a neighbourhood of every point of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @GradStudent So a function that is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ is entire or that's not the case? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does that means exactly @reuns ? Sorry for my dumbness, is there a way to write that more formally?

Comment: Entire $\Leftrightarrow$ holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: I suppose that by $|f(z)|^2 \leq C|z|^m$ you mean "there exists a $R\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|z| > R \implies f(z)|^2 \leq C|z|^m$" or else $\phi(x,y) = x+y+1$ breaks the theorem

Comment: That might be the case... If so, do you know how to formally prove the result? Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: There is no need to keep a date in the question, or to update it daily. If you want to bump the question to the front page then make *substantial* improvements.

Comment: Btw, you probably mean something like $|f(z)|^2 \le C(1+|z|)^m$, otherwise $f(z) = z+1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: That would also work... Thanks for the help and thanks for telling me the edit thing, I am kind of new and not familiar with some rules! Thanks!